# Show a box and do not fade it as long as the mouse is on it

Tags: javascript

Show a box and its axis as long as the mouse is on it

Hi
The box is displayed when the input key is pressed. The problem is that when I try to click on the box numbers when the box is displayed, the box is hidden.

Friends, how can I solve this problem?

```js
function show1() {
    document.getElementById("box1").style.display="block"
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById("box1").style.display="none"
}

function volcal(a) {
    document.querySelector("#number").value=a
}
```

```css
#number {
   opacity: 30%;
   padding: 3px;
}

 #number:hover {
   opacity: 100%;
   border-color: #ff0000;
   border-width: 1px;
   color: #0064ff;
}

#box1 {
   display: none;
   width: 30.5%;
   margin-right: 13px;
   padding: 3px;
   text-align: center;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #3b3b3b;
}
```

```html
<input id="number"  onblur="hide()" onfocus="show1()"  min="0" >

<span id="box1" style="display: non;"  onmouseout="hide()" onmouseover="show1()"> value =  
    <span class="me1" onclick="volcal(this.innerHTML)">
        1,000
    </span>
    <span class="wbb3" > | </span>
    <span class="me1"  onclick="volcal(this.innerHTML)">
        10,000
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using mouse out event to hide element you can use a click on a transparent background div that fill the entire screen, so when you click outside the box will hide.

```js
function show1() {
    document.getElementById("box1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("back-layer1").style.display = "block";
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById("box1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("back-layer1").style.display = "none";
}

function volcal(a) {
    document.querySelector("#number").value = a;
}
```

```css
#number {
    opacity: 30%;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

#number:hover {
    opacity: 100%;
    border-color: #ff0000;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #0064ff;
}

#box1 {
    display: none;
    width: 30.5%;
    margin-right: 13px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #3b3b3b;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}

#back-layer1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: transparent; /* change to red to see the behavior */
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="back-layer1" style="display: none" onclick="hide()"></div>
    <input id="number" onfocus="show1()" min="0" />
    <span id="box1" style="display: non" onmouseover="show1()">
        value =
        <span class="me1" onclick="volcal(this.innerHTML)"> 1,000 </span>
        <span class="wbb3"> | </span>
        <span class="me1" onclick="volcal(this.innerHTML)"> 10,000 </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to do these codes with jquery?@leo

Comment: @BestFriday you can change show and hide functions body to: `$("#box1, #back-layer1").show()` and `$("#box1, #back-layer1").hide()`, also you can change the value assignment to: `$("#number").val(a)`. I don't edited the question because I think this will be out of scope, but hope this help you

Comment: @BestFriday check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2o3v6jn4/